# Unique left inverse of linear transformation must also be a right inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

A linear transformation $T$ has at most one left inverse. If $L$ is a left inverse, must it also be a right inverse?

I have proved that, when the transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$ has a finite dimension, then the proposition is true. However, I haven't been able to prove the same for the infinite dimension case and I can't find a counterexample that has exactly one left inverse which is not a right inverse.

Comment: It is not true, even in finite dimensions, that left inverses are also right inverses. This is only true if the domain and codomain had the same finite dimension. For example, the matrix $[1, 0]$ has a right inverse but no left inverse.

Comment: @PedroAmaral, for finite dimensions, doesn't the uniqueness of the left inverse imply that $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$? Since $\exists$ left inverse $\Leftrightarrow T$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow \dim(Im(T))\geq \dim(V)$. And from the uniqueness, I thought we could conclude (after some work) that $\dim(Im(T))=\dim(W)=\dim(V)$

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. In that case you are correct as long as $dim(V) \neq 0$. If you restrict $V$ that way then a unique left inverse means the transformation is invertible and also has a unique right inverse. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conditions_for_Uniqueness_of_Left_Inverse_Mapping

Comment: So ($T$ has a left inverse $\Leftrightarrow T$ is injective) $\Rightarrow T$ is bijective. So, for all $y \in W, \exists x \in V$ s.t. $y=T(x)\Rightarrow L(y)=L(T(x))=x\Rightarrow T(L(y))=T(x)=y\Rightarrow L$ is also a right inverse. Is this correct? Thanks!